# Why is Pandas to_sql not working for me when I try to insert records with a chunksize of >1?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

Basically what I'm trying to do is use Pandas to insert a dataframe into a SQL table (Synapse). I can insert the data one record at a time but this isn't a practical solution. If I try to increase the number of records, I receive an error message.

I've tried to simplify the code I'm using down to the bare minimum here. The following code works fine when the chunksize is set to 1, but fails for any higher number. The full record set is around 500,000 rows, but the problem exists on just the 3 rows of test data I've created in the code below:

```
    SERVER = "xxx"
    DB = "xxx"
    USER = "xxx"
    PWD = "xxx"

    engine = sa.create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc://{USER}:{PWD}@{SERVER}/{DB}?'
                              'driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server'
                              '&autocommit=True')

    data = {
        'ColumnA': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'ColumnB': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
        'ColumnC': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
    }

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_sql('TESTING', engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=2, method='multi')
```

The error message I recieve is as follows:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Parse error at line: 1, column: 97: Incorrect syntax near ','. (103010) (SQLExecDirectW)")
[SQL: INSERT INTO [PBI_TESTING_MTC_TO_DELETE] ([ColumnA], [ColumnB], [ColumnC]) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: (1, 10, 100, 2, 20, 200)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/f405)
```

Is it significant that the parameters are inside one large tuple, rather than split into two? If so, have I missed something when creating the dataframe or building the data?

Comment: Synapse doesn't support that syntax https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest "Table value constructor is not supported in Azure Synapse Analytics. Instead, subsequent INSERT statements can be executed to insert multiple rows." It doesn't seem to support `VALUES` even as part of a `SELECT* FROM (VALUES` query. If you want a performant insert then maybe you can use COPY https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/copy-into-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest

Comment: Try `sa.create_engine(connection_url, fast_executemany=True)` with `.to_sql(…, method=None)` and see if that helps.